# Django admin with inlines, 1 model with 2 foreigns keys to 2 different models

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-admin

I have 3 models total. My main model has 2 foreign keys to 2 different models. So the relationships are setup as a many-to-one. When I try to customize the admin, I cannot get it to simply allow me to edit the main character model and have the 2 inlines (universe and series) show up.

What is the simplest way? There seams to be some ambiguity since the 2 foreign fields are throwing everything off. I have scoured the documentation but I must have missed something; I have gotten a more complex many-to-many working in the admin, so this is a bit odd.

Here are my models:

```
class CharacterSeries(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class CharacterUniverse(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200) 

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Character(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
    universe = models.ForeignKey(CharacterUniverse)    
    series = models.ForeignKey(CharacterSeries)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here is my admin:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Character, CharacterUniverse, CharacterSeries

# Register your models here.


class SeriesInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Character

class UniverseInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Character

class Characterdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        UniverseInline,
        SeriesInline,
   ]

admin.site.register(Character, CharacterAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

The code I posted earlier was **wrong**! I didn't read your models too carefully. Sorry about that.

If you want to create `CharacterSeries` and `CharacterUniverse` while you create/edit the `Character`, you could do this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Character, CharacterUniverse, CharacterSeries

# No need to define `ModelAdmin` classes

admin.site.register(Character)
admin.site.register(CharacterUniverse)
admin.site.register(CharacterSeries)
```

The code above will give you a **`+`** (plus) sign after the `universe` and `series` fields. This will help you create `CharacterUniverse` and `CharacterSeries` objects *on the fly*.

Comment: I get an internal server error with this when I refresh. ``admin.site.register(Character, CharacterAdmin)`` is the line causing it.

Comment: @klandshome Did you remove `class CharacterAdmin(...)` code from your admin.py file? If so, you weren't supposed to do that.

Comment: Nope it is still there.

Comment: @klandshome That's strange! What does the error message say?

Comment: It is an Apache server error:
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at *@* to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: OK so I had some extra code causing that Apache error. This is the real exception thrown: ``ValueError at /admin/character/character/add/

'character.CharacterUniverse' has no ForeignKey to 'character.Character'.``

Comment: @klandshome I made a mistake in the code. I feel terribly sorry for that. I've updated the answer, though.

Comment: Will try this out. Is there a way to make inlines works for reverse ``ForeignKey`` lookup? Also where is this specifically said in the documentation? Thanks.

Comment: Wow. It was that simple. Then why all this hub-hub about inlines? The doc need to be clearer here about the when and why to use them.

Comment: @klandshome *Inlines* have their use cases, too. Like, for example, in Django's default Poll tutorial. When you add a poll, you can add many choices to that poll by using *inlines*.

Comment: you did great; I understand now. Basically to make the inlines work I have to treat as so: When I add a universe, then I can add many characters to that using inlines. This is similar to your poll example.